# Should I cache md5 of file or is it fast enough to not need to?

Tags: php, md5, checksum

I need to check md5 checksum of ~10-20 files on server every time a user logs in. Each file can be ~10MB. Should I cache md5 of these files or do it in real-time without wasting time & bothering?

P. S. there will probably be up to 10k logins a day.

Comment: are the 10-20 files same for all users? or each user will have their own set of files?

Comment: files are same for all users

Comment: Why exactly do you need to do this…? Perhaps there's a much better overall approach to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the requirements, checking a cached value is not the same as getting a file checksum.

So based on the first sentence - *I need to check md5 checksum of ~10-20 files* - no, you cannot cache it.

However, if you just need to *display* a checksum, then yes, you can and should cache it and check the file-integrity periodically with a cron-job if necessary.

Comment: these files aren't modifiable by users, so they are the same for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are same for all users, then in that case I would suggest you to cache the `md5` of file so that each time you need not to get the file md5 and get it simply from cache.